# Chained Java Deep Copy?

Tags: java, deep-copy

I understand how to do a java deep copy using Serializable and Streams but as long as the object to copy has only primitive data types. In my case I have a parent class that contains among primitive data types an ArrayList of a child class, and they also need to be deep copied.

Can someone please point me to the right direction to do it?

UPDATE:

I thought it was working but I just realize it is not.

This is what I have.

```
public class Pack implements Serializable
      {
      String ID;
      String serviceCode;
      String name;
      String type;
      ArrayList<Service> services;
      public Pack deepClone()
      {
        try 
            {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
            oos.writeObject(this);

            ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
            Pack clone = (Pack) ois.readObject();
            clone.setID(null);
            clone.setType("Replica");
            return clone;
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
                {
                return null;
                }
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
                {
                    return null;
                }
        }
      }


public class Service implements Serializable
     {
     String ID;
     String serviceCode;
     String name;
     }
```

Now after cloning a Parent class a get a nice clone but the services array is null.

UPDATE:

Sorry my mistake, it was the lack of sleep. It is indeed working.

Comment: By "basic data types" do you mean primitives?

Comment: Uh yes, thank you, let me fix that.

Comment: Your understanding is wrong, it works on deep objects as well

Comment: I deep-copy by code or a Visitor class, never by serialization. Interesting concept but not what I'd use in practice.. This is a CS course idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to make sure the object of that array list also implements serializable, ie your child class

Comment: It wasn't me. Maybe my question was duplicated, I also received a vote to close thread. Sorry I couldn't find a similar question.

Comment: I thought it was working but now that I almost finish the App I realize that it is not deep copying. I'm going to add some code to be more clear.

Answer (score 4):

Serialization is done no matter either you have primitive data types or not. The only condition is that your child classes need to be serializable too.

Refer here for a quick tutorial [java_serialization](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'm going to check into it.